# notify user of not being able to update array

Tags: ios, iphone, notification, updating

I have an array of images that is loaded on my iphone through the internet. It is then cached.

If I don't have any internet or bad internet should I load the cached array with:

1. An on screen alert saying something like "The photos have not been updated" (even though the cache maybe up to date).
2. No notification of this action.

The user can update the array with a pull down refresh

Answer (score 1):

**Definitely give them an error message.** If your app has content that they would expect (i.e. photos shared by *them* on another device) to be there and it's not, you're going to get a lot of customer support calls. If you just say something like this:

> **Could not connect to internet!**
>
> Old images will be used. Check to make sure you have internet access.

It's simple, short, and easy to code. There's no reason not to tell them that.

> The user can update the array with a pull down refresh

No offense, but expect your user base to be *dumb* when using technology. You may think *oh, you just pull down to refresh*, but often users don't think that way. Refresh often, tell them if something goes wrong, and let them refresh manually if they wish.

Comment: Yes but the images will still appear as they are cached... So it won't look as if anything has gone wrong!

Comment: @Maximilian I suggest you go and disconnect your iPhone (if you have one) from WiFi/3G. It shows you an error, but it leaves all the previous emails there. I don't think that's bad: the user has been warned and they can still access content.